# Why does Interstellar Probe need 2 TB of memory

Tags: probe, data-transmission, flight-computer, data-storage

[This article](https://www.science.org/content/article/voyager-steroids-mission-probe-mysterious-region-beyond-solar-system) says that [Interstellar Probe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_Probe_(spacecraft)) is supposed to have two terabytes of memory(which I assume means storage, not RAM). What does it need so much for? [New Horizons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) had 8 gigabytes of storage, mainly because it was doing a flyby and caching data to be transmitted later. According to the same infographic, it would take about 30 years to transmit all of the data from 150 AU, which is possible, but why couldn't they cache smaller amounts and transmit more often?

Comment: What do you mean by "transmit more often"? More often than a continuous data stream of 30 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

McNutt, Ralph et al ["Interstellar Probe: Humanity's Journey to Interstellar Space"](https://interstellarprobe.jhuapl.edu/Interstellar-Probe-MCR.pdf) seems to be the primary source about this mission.

The mission is to send a spacecraft similar to Voyagers on a high-speed trajectory up to a distance of 1000 AU.

In the early mission up to 20 AU they expect to produce about 20 kb/s of science data, which drops down to 0.05 kb/s for the mission beyond 350 AU. (table 4-4)

Likewise, the available transmission bandwidth drops from >1 Mb/s down to 1 kb/s (or even 50 b/s when using current DSN resources). (figure 5-4)

They plan to download data on a weekly schedule of 8 hours transmission time each week, and more frequent contacts in the first part of the journey (table 3-4).

Regarding the available storage capacity they write:

> The data recorder on Interstellar Probe is presumed to be able to hold
> at a minimum data from the early solar system accumulated over the
> course of a year, or ~600 Gbit.

Later in the mission one year worth of data would be about 1.5 Gbit, so there remains plenty of space for mitigations of errors in the memory, e.g. induced by radiation accumulated throughout the > 50 years journey.

I can't find any reference to the "2 TByte" (27 times more than proposed) claimed in your linked article though. As you found, a memory huge like this wouldn't make much sense on a probe unless you plan to store data for ages and retrieve it physically a couple centuries from now.

Actually, the total amount of data expected during a 100 year lifetime is only about 3 Tbit (table 4-4), so still short of 2 TByte by a factor of 5.

Comment: the memory claim in the science.org article is in the figure that compares the Voyager and Interstellar Probe missions, written as "2 terabytes"

Comment: @ErinAnne Yes, but as I wrote I can't find it anywhere else.

Comment: Possibly a result of redundant storage systems and someone mixing up bits and bytes.